# How to set variables for a script task when not having task id?

Tags: activiti

I have following flow in process definition:

> user-task -> script-task

In my java application code, I set user task to complete. This triggers scrip task automatically.

What I want is to set some variables which are used only in script task. Taskservice.setVariableLocal() method needs task id, which I don't have when I set user task to complete from application code.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an executionListener to set the variable?

Answer (score 0):

How are you completing the task without having the Id? You can use a listener, but still, the whole idea of having user tasks
Is that each user can get his/her assigned tasks using the task service. When they do that, you get access to the id

Comment: id is of user task, not script task. I want to set variables in script task.

Comment: The script task doesn’t have its own id because it will run, finish and move on. And it also doesn’t have it’s own context meaning that it will use process scope varibles